# Getting List of shared drives from Google drive

Tags: java, mule

I am trying to get list of shared drives from google drive and check whether a drive is present in list of drives returned.

am using http method
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives

which returns me below output.

```
{
    "kind": "drive#driveList",
    "drives": [
        {
            "kind": "drive#drive",
            "id": "0AKrgo4Gdm2hzUk9PVA",
            "name": "Dev"
        }]
}
```

need to check whether the drive "Dev" is present or  not.  If yes i need its id as output. If not "Not found".

Am able to achieve this through http connection. How can i achieve this through Java method?

Code am trying is below:

```
public static  String driveName(String driveName,String oauthToken){
            String driveId = null;
            File file = null;
            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();
            credential.setAccessToken(oauthToken);

            _teamdrives = new Drive.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential).setApplicationName("mulesoftgdrive").build();
                    
            file = _teamdrives.drives().get(driveId).execute();
            return driveId;
```

Comment: This question seems to be about using Java to programmatically access Google Drive. There is no Mule part in it. Should we remove the `mule` tag?

Comment: I will be using this java code inside Mulesoft for accessing google drive. If that concerns can remove it.

Comment: It just doesn't seem to be relevant, unless you make and process the REST API calls with Mule components.